# GetX controller not getting initialized (onInit not getting called) the second time

Tags: flutter, dart, controller, flutter-getx

Here is the skeleton of my code:

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {
....
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Home({super.key});
  final controller = Get.put(HomeController());
....
  Column(
    children:[
      WorkoutListWidget()
    ....
]
```

and `WorkoutListWidget` is written like so:

```
class WorkoutListWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  WorkoutListWidget({super.key});
  final controller = Get.put(WorkoutController());
....
```

`WorkoutController` is written like so:

```
class WorkoutController extends GetxController {
  static WorkoutController get instance => Get.find();
  
  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchData(); // <<<---- This is what does not work for me.
    super.onInit();
  }
```

Everything works fine till here. The `WorkoutController` `onInit` is called and the data is displayed using GetX and Obx etc.

The problem arises when a user after navigating to the `WorkoutCreate` page/route and after creating/submitting the form and navigating away from the `WorkoutCreateWidget` back to `Home`

```
class WorkoutCreateWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  WorkoutCreateWidget({super.key});
  // The same controller that was Get.put as part of the WorkoutListWidget
  final controller = Get.put(WorkoutController());
  
  ...

  onPressed: () {
     workoutController.saveWorkout();
     workoutFormKey.currentState?.reset();
     Get.delete<WorkoutController>();
     Get.offNamed(Routes.home); // <<<--- Navigating back to the home page to view the just created Workout
  }
```

on navigating back to the Home page, the `WorkoutController` does not call `onInit`, and the just recently created Workout, does not get displayed on the Home page.

I have two questions:

1. Why does the `onInit` function not get called when navigating back to the Home page, even though Widgets have done a `Get.put` (no `lazyput` or `find` or `permanent: true`)
2. Is it bad practice to use one single controller to have logic for both - getting a list of model objects for that feature AND creating a model object?

Thanks for taking the time to read through this problem

Comment: Can you please share WorkoutCreateWidget code.

Comment: @Mihirpatel, Its already shared in the question. The last code snippet is that of WorkoutCreateWidget

Comment: Can you please do one thing, take one variable in controller and WorkoutCreateWidget  build method print that variable. Now you can check your init method working or not? let me know